# Steps to Changing the SharePoint 2019 Farm Account Password

Tags: sharepoint-server, administration, 2019

I am trying to change the password for Farm Account in SharePoint server 2019

Can you please help me with the steps for changing the password for Farm Account in SharePoint server 2019 (not SP 2013)?

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps to change Farm Account Password on the UI：

1.Go to your SharePoint Central Administration site >> Click on Security >> Configure Managed Accounts
[image]

2.Click on the “Edit” icon next to the SharePoint Farm account.

3.Tick the “Change password now” check box and set the “Use existing password” option
4.Enter the password (password which is already changed in AD) of the account and click on OK to update the password of the SharePoint farm account.
[image]

Here are steps to change Farm Account Password using PowerShell：

```
#Get the Farm Account
$FarmAccount = Read-Host "Enter the Farm Account in Domain\User Format:"
  
#Get the changed Password for the farm account
$Password = Read-Host "Enter the New password for Farm Account" -AsSecureString
  
#Update the password for farm account
Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $FarmAccount -NewPassword $Password -ConfirmPassword $Password
```